# HealthKit Swift getting today's steps

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am making a swift iOS app that integrates with a user's step count as reported by the Health app. I can easily find the user's step count in the last hour, using this as my predicate:

```
let anHourBeforeNow: NSDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-60 * 60)
let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(anHourBeforeNow, endDate: NSDate(), options: .None)
```

And I have the rest down, so I can successfully access the user's step count for the last hour. **But how can I access the user's step data since the day began, like the Health app displays in the steps section?**

I am trying to do something like this:

```
let date = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let newDate = cal.startOfDayForDate(date)
let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(newDate, endDate: NSDate(), options: .None)
```

but this code does not adjust for time zone (so it gives me the beginning of the day in UTC, not the beginning of the day where the user is) and I am also getting highly inflated step counts (for reasons unknown).

**So how can I get the user's step count for the current day, with the same number of steps as reported in Health, like pictured here:**[image]

Comment: this can help you see the swift answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29582462/get-total-step-count-for-every-date-in-healthkit

Comment: You should include the code for your query and how you calculate the step count so we can help you with this issue. You may also follow my responses to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560367/health-handles-multiple-step-sources-differently-than-healthkit-swift for guidance if it turns out you are making the same mistake.

Comment: What does NSTimeZone.localTimeZone() return in your app?

Comment: The answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560367/health-handles-multiple-step-sources-differently-than-healthkit-swift

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is the right way using HKStatisticsCollectionQuery courtesy of the direction from the code above.

This is written in Swift 3 so you may have to convert some of the code back to 2.3 or 2 if not on 3 yet.

**Swift 3**

```
 func retrieveStepCount(completion: (stepRetrieved: Double) -> Void) {

        //   Define the Step Quantity Type
        let stepsCount = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)

        //   Get the start of the day         
        let date = Date()
        let cal = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
        let newDate = cal.startOfDay(for: date)

        //  Set the Predicates & Interval
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: newDate, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
        var interval = DateComponents()
        interval.day = 1

        //  Perform the Query
        let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: stepsCount!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: [.cumulativeSum], anchorDate: newDate as Date, intervalComponents:interval)

        query.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in

            if error != nil {

                //  Something went Wrong
                return
            }

            if let myResults = results{
                myResults.enumerateStatistics(from: self.yesterday, to: self.today) {
                    statistics, stop in

                    if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {

                        let steps = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())

                        print("Steps = \(steps)")
                        completion(stepRetrieved: steps)

                    }
                }
            }


        }

        storage.execute(query)
    }
```

**Objective-C**

```
HKQuantityType *type = [HKSampleType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startOfDay = [[NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian] startOfDayForDate:today];

NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:startOfDay endDate:today options:HKQueryOptionStrictStartDate];
NSDateComponents *interval = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
interval.day = 1;

HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query = [[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc] initWithQuantityType:type quantitySamplePredicate:predicate options:HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum anchorDate:startOfDay intervalComponents:interval];

query.initialResultsHandler = ^(HKStatisticsCollectionQuery * _Nonnull query, HKStatisticsCollection * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
  if (error != nil) {
    // TODO
  } else {
    [result enumerateStatisticsFromDate:startOfDay toDate:today withBlock:^(HKStatistics * _Nonnull result, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
      HKQuantity *quantity = [result sumQuantity];
      double steps = [quantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit countUnit]];
      NSLog(@"Steps : %f", steps);
    }];
  }
};

[self.storage executeQuery:query];
```

Comment: @Gugulethu can you please guide how Can I truncate manually added steps from this ?

Comment: @Byte Just trying to understand your questions -  You want to truncate steps added manually from another source apart from HealthKit?

Comment: NO, I want to get al the steps detected by iphone, and automatically added by other  trackers. But I do not want those steps which users added manually into health app.

Comment: That I do not really know how to do yet! Will do some research and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: @Gugulethu and can you please convert your answer to swift 2 and post it ?

Comment: @dimple Please explain further? Are you not able to retrieve the steps using that function?

Comment: Bit of an overkill to use HKStatisticsCollectionQuery just to get today's steps. Use HKStatisticsQuery instead.

Comment: HKStatisticsCollectionQuery is an overkill and complicates things. For your need use HKStatisticsQuery (The answer below).

Comment: i have issue in both query HKStatisticsCollectionQuery & HKStatisticsQuery . getting today's data only from HK but it not give exact in healthkit. issue raised in client country only.

Comment: Where are self.yesterday and self.today comming from?

Answer (score 56):

HKStatisticsCollectionQuery is better suited to use when you want to retrieve data over a time span. Use HKStatisticsQuery to just get the steps for a specific date.

**Swift 5:**

```
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

func getTodaysSteps(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
    
    let now = Date()
    let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(
        withStart: startOfDay,
        end: now,
        options: .strictStartDate
    )
    
    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(
        quantityType: stepsQuantityType,
        quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, 
        options: .cumulativeSum
    ) { _, result, _ in
        guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
            completion(0.0)
            return
        }
        completion(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()))
    }
    
    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

Comment: This solution is simpler and more efficient than the accepted one.

Comment: @Jose can you please Answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620547/how-to-get-apple-health-data-by-date-wise

Comment: Sure, I posted an example.

Comment: Can we get separate count of running and walking steps count ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Yeah, you just need to use a different quantityType.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the total number of step for each day, over a period of time, then use [HKStatisticsCollectionQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery), code in Swift 4.2

```
let startDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(-3600 * 24 * 7)
let endDate = Date()

let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(
  withStart: startDate,
  end: endDate,
  options: [.strictStartDate, .strictEndDate]
)

// interval is 1 day
var interval = DateComponents()
interval.day = 1

// start from midnight
let calendar = Calendar.current
let anchorDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())

let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(
  quantityType: HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!,
  quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
  options: .cumulativeSum,
  anchorDate: anchorDate!,
  intervalComponents: interval
)

query.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in
  guard let results = results else {
    return
  }

  results.enumerateStatistics(
    from: startDate,
    to: endDate,
    with: { (result, stop) in
      let totalStepForADay = result.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()) ?? 0
    }
  )
}

store.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 5):

The query you were using takes all of the user's recorded steps from Healthkit, not doing the smart filter-out of duplicative steps the Health app does. Instead, you want to get the aggregated step data that the Health app produces after combining steps from different sources to get an accurate tally.

To do that, you can use this code:

```
func recentSteps2(completion: (Double, NSError?) -> () )
{ // this function gives you all of the steps the user has taken since the beginning of the current day.

    checkAuthorization() // checkAuthorization just makes sure user is allowing us to access their health data.
    let type = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount) // The type of data we are requesting


    let date = NSDate()
    let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    let newDate = cal.startOfDayForDate(date)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(newDate, endDate: NSDate(), options: .None) // Our search predicate which will fetch all steps taken today

    // The actual HealthKit Query which will fetch all of the steps and add them up for us.
    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: type!, predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: nil) { query, results, error in
        var steps: Double = 0

        if results?.count > 0
        {
            for result in results as! [HKQuantitySample]
            {
                steps += result.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())
            }
        }

        completion(steps, error)
    }

    storage.executeQuery(query)
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not correct. HKSampleQuery returns every step record (it does not remove duplicates) and is an inefficient way to compute the sum of samples matching a predicate. You should be using HKStatisticsQuery.

Answer (score 5):

**For swift 4.2**

**1) Get HealthKitPermission**

```
import HealthKit

func getHealthKitPermission() {

    delay(0.1) {
        guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
            return
        }

        let stepsCount = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!

        self.healthkitStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [], read: [stepsCount]) { (success, error) in
            if success {
                print("Permission accept.")
            }
            else {
                if error != nil {
                    print(error ?? "")
                }
                print("Permission denied.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2) To get steps count for specific date**

```
func getStepsCount(forSpecificDate:Date, completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
        let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
        let (start, end) = self.getWholeDate(date: forSpecificDate)

        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: start, end: end, options: .strictStartDate)

        let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { _, result, _ in
            guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
                completion(0.0)
                return
            }
            completion(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()))
        }

        self.healthKitStore.execute(query)
    }

    func getWholeDate(date : Date) -> (startDate:Date, endDate: Date) {
        var startDate = date
        var length = TimeInterval()
        _ = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .day, start: &startDate, interval: &length, for: startDate)
        let endDate:Date = startDate.addingTimeInterval(length)
        return (startDate,endDate)
    }
```

**How to use**

```
self.getStepsCount(forSpecificDate: Date()) { (steps) in
                if steps == 0.0 {
                    print("steps :: \(steps)")
                }
                else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("steps :: \(steps)")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the above answers and from Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkstatisticsquery
I got the following to work in swift 2.3 on Xcode 8.0.

```
class func getStepCountHealth(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate, completion:(Double?, NSError?)->()) {

            let healthKitStore:HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()

            //   Define the sample type
            let sampleType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(
            HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)

            //  Set the predicate
            let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate,
                                                                 endDate: endDate, options: .None)
            // build the query
            let sampleQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: sampleType!,
                                      quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
                                      options: .CumulativeSum) { query, results, error in

                                        if results != nil {
                                            let quantity = results?.sumQuantity()
                                            let unit = HKUnit.countUnit()
                                            let totalSteps = quantity?.doubleValueForUnit(unit)
                                            completion(totalSteps, error)
//                                            print("totalSteps for \(endDate) are \(totalSteps!)")
                                        } else {
                                            completion(nil, error)
//                                            print("results are nil")
                                            return
                                        } 
                                    }
            // execute the Query
            healthKitStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)
        }
```