# How to get Apple health data by date wise?

Tags: swift, healthkit, hksamplequery

**Apple health app gives the data by Date wise as shown in below image.**

[image]

By using `HealthKit` i am fetching the steps data from apple health
as

```
let p1 = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: fromDate, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
let p2 = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey: HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered, operatorType: .notEqualTo, value: true)
let timeSortDesriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)//as in health kit entry
let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: fromDate, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
let sourceQuery = HKSourceQuery(sampleType: quantityType, samplePredicate: predicate, completionHandler: { query,sources,error in

if sources?.count != 0  && sources != nil {

                let lastIndex = sources!.count - 1
                var sourcesArray = Array(sources!)
                for i in 0..<sourcesArray.count {
                    let sourcePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: sourcesArray[i])
                    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p1, p2,sourcePredicate])
                    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: quantityType, predicate: predicate, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, sortDescriptors: [timeSortDesriptor], resultsHandler: { query, results, error in
                        guard let samples = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
                            return
                        }......
```

sourceQuery gives multiple object like Apple watch, My iPhone.
further i am using for loop with `HKSampleQuery` which gives `HKQuantitySample` object. 
Problem is `[HKQuantitySample]` gives Array of step data which is not sorted datewise. 
I am looking for data which are club for the date like what apple health show in Health app.

Yes there is workaround like manually sort the data from `[HKQuantitySample]` by date wise. but there may be workaround by using `predicates` or something else. Please feel free to ask if you need any extra information.

**EDIT: As suggested by @Allan**
I have added [HKStatisticsCollectionQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery), YES it gives data **datewise** but the steps count receiving is not same as in Apple health App. is something Addition/modification required in below code ?

```
let last10Day = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -10, to: Date())!
        var interval = DateComponents()
        interval.day = 1
        let quantityType1 = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
        // Create the query
        let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: quantityType1,
                                                quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                                options: .cumulativeSum,
                                                anchorDate: last10Day,
                                                intervalComponents: interval)
        // Set the results handler
        query.initialResultsHandler = {
            query, results, error in

            guard let statsCollection = results else {
                // Perform proper error handling here
                fatalError("*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription)) ***")
            }
            let endDate = Date()
            statsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: last10Day, to: endDate, with: { (statistics, stop) in
                if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
                    let date = statistics.startDate
                    let value = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
                    print("--value-->",value, ",--For Date-->",date)
                }
            })
        }
            healthStore.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` to fetch data from a certain period. Here is an example showing how to fetch steps for the last 30 days:

```
private let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
private let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!

func importStepsHistory() {
    let now = Date()
    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -30, to: now)!

    var interval = DateComponents()
    interval.day = 1

    var anchorComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: now)
    anchorComponents.hour = 0
    let anchorDate = Calendar.current.date(from: anchorComponents)!

    let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(
        quantityType: stepsQuantityType,
        quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
        options: [.cumulativeSum],
        anchorDate: anchorDate,
        intervalComponents: interval
    ) 
    query.initialResultsHandler = { _, results, error in
        guard let results = results else {
            log.error("Error returned form resultHandler = \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            return
        }
    
        results.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate, to: now) { statistics, _ in
            if let sum = statistics.sumQuantity() {
                let steps = sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
                print("Amount of steps: \(steps), date: \(statistics.startDate)")
            }
        }
    }

    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

Comment: Jose you are the **BOSS** 

Comment: Saved the day!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want totals for step count separated by day like in the Health app, you should use `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery`, not `HKSampleQuery`. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery) provides example code for grouping results by week, but you can modify it group by day instead.