# Convert swift 2.x to swift 3 problems

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have made this function to get all steps for each day but I want to convert this function from swift 2.x to swift 3. But I get stuck on 2 different points.

```
let anchorDate = calendar.dateComponents(anchorComponents)
```

**I get this error:** Cannot invoke dateCompontents with an argument of list type (Datecomponents)

---

And on this point:

```
let stepsQuery = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: HKQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: nil, options: .CumulativeSum, anchorDate: anchorComponents!, intervalComponents: interval)
```

**Error:** Cannot convert value of type HKQuantityType.Type to expected argument type HKQuantityType.

---

The complete function:

```
func getDailySteps(){
            let calendar = NSCalendar.current
            let interval = NSDateComponents()
            interval.day = 1

        var anchorComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day , .month , .year], from: NSDate() as Date)
        anchorComponents.hour = 0
        let anchorDate = calendar.dateComponents(anchorComponents)

        // Define 1-day intervals starting from 0:00
        let stepsQuery = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: HKQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: nil, options: .CumulativeSum, anchorDate: anchorComponents!, intervalComponents: interval)

        // Set the results handler
        stepsQuery.initialResultsHandler = {query, results, error in
            let endDate = NSDate()
            let startDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -7, toDate: endDate, options: [])
            if let myResults = results{                                                                             myResults.enumerateStatisticsFromDate(startDate!, toDate: endDate) { statistics, stop in
                if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity(){
                    let date = statistics.startDate
                    let steps = quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())
                    print("\(date): steps = \(steps)")
                    //NOTE: If you are going to update the UI do it in the main thread
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                        //update UI components
                    }

                }
                } //end block
            } //end if let
        }

        HKHealthStore?.executeQuery(stepsQuery)

    }
```

So how can I convert this method to swift 3 ?

Comment: Ah. I see this is just copy pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/38875920/4822221 Make some attempt to fix your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code contains some more errors than you describe. I copied your code into a playground tried to fix it. I can't guarantee that it will work (I have never worked with *HealthKit* before, but it should at least compile.

### Error 0*

In Swift 3, some classes have been renamed. For example `NSCalendar` to `Calendar`. The first two lines within your function have to be changed to this:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var interval = DateComponents()
```

### Error 1

To get a date from date components, you have to use this function:

```
calendar.date(from: anchorComponents)
```

### Error 2:

After reading the documentation about [HKStatisticsCollectionQuery](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery) and [HKQuantityType](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkquantitytype) I came up with this line of code:

```
let stepsQuery = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!, quantitySamplePredicate: nil, options: .cumulativeSum, anchorDate: anchorDate!, intervalComponents: interval)
```

`HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)` replaces the `HKQuantityType` in your old code.

`anchorDate:` receives a `Date` instead of `DateComponents`.

And the enum-case you pass to `options:` starts with a lowercase letter in Swift 3.

### Error 3*

`dateByAddingUnit` has been changed. In Swift 3, you use this:

```
calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: endDate)
```

(Again, the enum-case now starts with a lowercase letter.)

### Error 4*

`enumerateStatistics` has been changed, too. It's now:

```
enumerateStatistics(from: startDate!, to: endDate)
```

### Error 5*

`HKUnit.countUnit()` has been renamed:

```
let steps = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
```

### Error 6*

The way to use multiple threads has been changed massively.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //update UI components
}
```

### Error 7*

`HKHealthStore?.executeQuery(stepsQuery)` is a bit strange. `execute(_:)` (as it is named in Swift 3) is not static and can only be used on instances of `HKHealthStore`. I fixed the error-message with the following line, but I'm not sure, if this will really work.

```
HKHealthStore().execute(stepsQuery)
```

---

*Additional errors I have found in your code when using it in a Playground.

Answer (score 0):

.dateComponents was removed as part of better translating Objective-C APIs into swift: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md

Try

```
calendar.date(from: DateComponents)
```

As far as your healthkit issues, I suspect you need something more along the lines of

```
HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount
```

Rather than the entire HKQuantityType class.